How to ensure ingesting logs to only one specific log type using google SecOps log ingestion API
If I provide access to the log ingestion API in chronicle, how can I make sure that an external application can only ingest logs to a specific log type and cannot tamper with the integrity of other log types ?
I am currently exploring a lead related to IAM conditions, can this be a viable solution ?
